# How to replace duplicate code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me solve this problem.  I made a filter for parters list. It works, but my code is repeated code (not DRY):

```
  def index
    if (params[:fld_status] == nil) || (params[:fld_status] == '')
      @users = User.where("name LIKE :query", query: "%#{params[:fld_name]}%").paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order(created_at: :DESC)        
    else
      @users = User.where(status_id: params[:fld_status]).where("name LIKE :query", query: "%#{params[:fld_name]}%").paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order(created_at: :DESC)  
    end
  end
```

I need to refactor out the duplicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to make an [named scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) first inside the `User` model.

```
scope :paginate_users, 
      -> (query, page) do
            where("name LIKE :query", query: query)
            .paginate(page: page, :per_page => 10)
            .order(created_at: :DESC)
      end
```

Then Inside the controller :

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate_users("%#{params[:fld_name]}%", params[:page])
  @users = @users.where(status_id: params[:fld_status]) if params[:fld_status].present?
end
```